How to run cypress tests using regression or smoke tags in nx workspace
I have a cypress project set up. I need to run cypress tests based on tags using nx command.
cypress grep--->"@cypress/grep": "^4.0.1"
I applied nx command. eg: nx run e2e:e2e --tags=@regression
But the nx project is identifying all test cases in cypress, it does not take into consideration the test cases tagged with tag @regression
Can someone guide me if there is a provision in nx command to run cypress tests based on tags.
My spec file will be like below
filename.cy.ts
describe('', { tags: "@regression"}, () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.login();
  });

  it('', { tags: "@regression"},() => {
  
  });

My e2e.ts file:-
import './commands';
import registerCypressGrep from "@cypress/grep";
registerCypressGrep();

My project.json file:-
{
  "name": "",
  "$schema": "../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "sourceRoot": "e2e/src",
  "projectType": "application",
  "targets": {
    "e2e": {
      "executor": "@nx/cypress:cypress",
      "options": {
        "cypressConfig": "e2e/cypress.config.ts",
        "devServerTarget": "",
        "testingType": "e2e"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "devServerTarget": ""
        }
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "executor": "@nx/eslint:lint",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"]
    }
  },
  "tags": ["@regression"],
  "implicitDependencies": [""]
}


You should be able to pass the tag in via the -e CLI option
nx e2e frontend-e2e -e=grepTag=@regression

or
nx run e2e:e2e -e=grepTag=@regression

or
nx e2e frontend-e2e --env.grepTag="@regression"


no its not helpful.still its running all test case including regression. i need only regression tag test to run.

It's probably just a mistake in your configuration.
